# Highlight a row in table html which has a value exceed the avg

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is looks like this. [image: MyTable]

What I want to do is, I want to Highlight (Yellow COLOR) which row has USAGE PER 1K Higher than the AVERAGE. The result should looks like this.
[image]

Here is my code to make a row been hightlight when exceed value of average, but I cannot change the value `if($row['duh']>'0.77')` to the `if($row['duh']>'$avg')` because it will hightlight all the rows.

```
$no   = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $month1=strtotime($row['month']);
  $month=date('m-Y',$month1);
  $store_name=$row['store_name'];
  $netamt1=$row['netamt'];
  $netamt11=number_format($netamt1,2);
  $usage1=$row['monusage'];
  $usage11=number_format($usage1,2);
  $answer=$usage1/$netamt1*1000;
  $answer1=number_format($answer,2);
  $total+=$answer1;
  $avg=$total/$no;
  $duh = number_format($row['duh'],2);

   echo "<tr>"; 
   echo "<td>".$no."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$store_name."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$date2111."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$netamt11."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$usage11."</td>";  
   if($row['duh']>'0.77') {// 0.77 i cannot change to $avg, because it will hightlight all the rows become yellow
   echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFF00;'>".$duh."</td>";}
   else {
       echo "<td>".$duh."</td>";
    } 
   echo "</tr>"; 
  $no++;
}?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">TOTAL</th>
    <th><?=($total)?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th colspan="5">AVERAGE</th>
  <th><?=number_format($avg,4)?></th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: i think the right value of $avg is not being taken up try logging $avg to see if it has right value

Comment: because the $avg is read row by row in 'while'. the value of $avg is not the final value, that why all rows been hightlighted. I want it compare with the final value of $avg. How to do that.

Comment: get $avg from sql query seems someone already answered that

Answer (score 1):

You can add `avegage` as another column in query result and compare the values against it, e.g.:

```
SELECT no, outlet, date, sales, usage, usage_per_1k, AVG(usage_per_1k) AS avg
FROM table
WHERE condition;
```

AND then, add the following to highlight:

```
if($row['duh']>$row['avg']) {
   hightlight all the rows become yellow
   echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFF00;'>".$duh."</td>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah good idea. but I think I cannot use another query because my $result that been fetch is to get the data into the table and the formulation of avg is calculate by $total/$no. And the usage per 1k is calculate by Sales/Usage*1000

Answer (score 0):

After keep trying,  now i figure out how to hightlight a row depending on the condition average, if Higher than average, the row will Yellow, but I make it RED now. If Lower than average, the color will not change. Im using script in `<body> tag`, and add `class in <tr> tag`, then do function.

```
$no   = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $month1=strtotime($row['month']);
  $month=date('m-Y',$month1);
  $store_name=$row['store_name'];
  $netamt1=$row['netamt'];
  $netamt11=number_format($netamt1,2);
  $usage1=$row['monusage'];
  $usage11=number_format($usage1,2);
  $answer=$usage1/$netamt1*1000;
  $answer1=number_format($answer,2);
  $duh = number_format($row['duh'],2);
  $total+=$duh;
  $avg=$total/$no;


   echo "<tr class='y_n';>"; 
   echo "<td>".$no."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$store_name."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$date2111."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$netamt11."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$usage11."</td>";  
   $no++;
   echo "<td>".$duh."</td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 
} ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#table_id tr.y_n td').each(function() {
     if ($(this).text() >=<?=number_format($avg,2)?>) {
         $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#fc9c9c');
                               }
                               else
                                $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#e5f5ff');

                                             });
</script> 
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">TOTAL</th>
    <th><?=($total)?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th colspan="5">AVERAGE</th>
  <th><?=number_format($avg,4)?></th></tr>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="6"><center><?php echo $actionstatus?></center></th>
 </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Here is the Result :
[image: Result]